# Create html layout similar to android

Tags: html, css

I have a `WebView` that displays a html layout. But the problem is the html layout isn't coming out how I expected it. I created a Android layout using xml but I want the layout in html. this is what i am trying trying achieve

The grey part represents a background image.
The purple part a image(Logo).
Then I have a white box with round corners and `TextView` and `Button` inside. this is done in android xml but i want something similar in html

[image: Layout in android xml]

This is how it looks in html

[image: Layout in html]

But as you can see the logo is behind the white box and the `TextView` is next to the button instead of the top.

here is my html code

```
<style>

    div {
        padding: 10px 10px;
        background: #fff;
        width: 300px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin : 0 auto;
    }
    body {
        background-image: url("url to background image");
        //background-size: cover;
    }
    .logo {
        background-image: url("url to logo");
        background-size: cover;
        height:  70px;
        width: 200px;
        margin-bottom 40;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    .container {
        display: table;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    .helper {
        #position: absolute;
        #top: 50%;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    .content {
        #position: relative;
        #top: -50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 200px;
    }
    .button {
        -moz-border-radius:15px;
        -webkit-border-radius:15px;
        border-radius:15px;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="helper">

      <div class="logo"/>

        <div class="content">

          <p1>Text </p1>

            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Button">

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Can someone please help me fix my html code to look like the android xml version

Answer (score 0):

Change `<p1>Text </p1>` to `<p>Text </p>`.

A `p` element has the style `display:block;` by default and will push the button down.

Comment: Thanks for the help. but any idea why the logo is behind white box instead of above

Comment: @RichardKMaleho Might be because you have a lot of invalid css. You have unnecessary '#', like: `#position: absolute;`